# How to call a function variable in another function having the same class in core php

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

```
class DB_conn{  
    function getConnected($servername,$useranem,$pass,$db) {    
    $mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $useranem, $pass, $db);
    if($mysqli->connect_error) 
        die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '. mysqli_connect_error());
    return $mysqli;
    }
```

This is my connection string function, I am using `mysqli`. I have to use two parameters for the `mysqli` query. How to call `$mysqli` in the next function? When I am using `$mysqli` in the `fetch_login` function, it's giving me an error of undefined variable.

> Notice: Undefined property: DB_conn::$mysqli in 
>      D:\xampp\htdocs\mysqli\connect.php on line 44

```
public function fetch_login(){
    //$mysqli; 
    $sql = mysqli_query($mysqli,"select * from login");
    return $sql;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use $this keyword before variable and function to access class members

```
class DB_conn
{  
    private $mysqli;

    public function getConnected($servername,$useranem,$pass,$db)
    {    
        $mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $useranem, $pass, $db);
        if($mysqli->connect_error) 
            die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '. mysqli_connect_error());
        return $mysqli;
    }
    public function fetch_login()
    {
      //$mysqli; 
       $sql = mysqli_query($this->$mysqli,"select * from login");
       return $sql;
    }
}
```